# bootstrap panel-header change height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change height of [bootstraps](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels) panel-header, if I change the height using this css:

```
style="height: 20px;"
```

The title inside the header will be missplaced

[See example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fsQO7386Akn3hs3nUtMn?p=preview) on plunker

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a good idea what you did, but if you still want to stick with it, then you have to change bootstrap's default *panel-heading padding* too, like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/UJBznitBfori5brjg9D3?p=preview) to your panel:

```
 <div style="height: 20px;padding:0" class="panel-heading">
```

as you can see in the plunker the `font-size` is not the most desirable size so I suggest you to use custom class and not bootstraps `.panel-heading`

Comment: I see, in my application I felt that it was just slightly too big, but I would not like to create issues just for that little fix. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @klskl glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

Just don't do that: The height of this element (including all the text in there, also the second paragraph) adjusts automatically to the text (so that ALL text has the background defined in there). If you manually set the height (as you did), the text will still be visible (since overlapping text is shown), but it won't fit the background.

Try adding some text and you'll realize, what I mean.